# jQuery UI droppable doesn't work on IE and Firefox (but does on Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, firefox

My jQuery UI droppable doesn't work on IE or Firefox, but does on Chrome.

```
    function drawNVDGraph(targetElement, data, type) {
    nv.addGraph(function () {

       // here I make some graph this works        

            $("#NVDGraph" + targetElement).draggable();
    $("#NVDGraph" + targetElement).draggable("option", "cursor","url(smiley.jpg), cell");    
        //drag works fine I can see the cursor change


  $("#NVDGraph" + targetElement).on( "drag", function( event, ui ) {
          // here I just block the graph so it doesn't move       
     ui.position.left = 0;
      ui.position.right = 0;
          ui.position.top = 0;
      ui.position.bottom = 0;
     //masterSVG = data;


  } );



   $("#NVDGraph" + targetElement).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {
         // this doesn't work on FF or IE or EDGE the drop isn't even detected
      console.log("hello");

            var data1 = sinAndCos();            
            var data2 = sinAndCos2();


       var data3 =  data1.concat(data2);
       drawNVDGraph(targetElement, data3, type); 

     console.log(data3);          
  } );
```

To explain the code a bit, I have 2 dialog boxes that both have a graph inside. What I want to do is drag the data from one graph to the other. (That's why I have `ui.position.left = 0;` and I show a smiley to say "I have the data".) Again, it works like a charm on Chrome but only on Chrome.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the dev console (F12) ?

Comment: Are you able to recreate the issue so we can see it? e.g. using codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: No error in dev console, and  sadly I can't do a jsfiddle the project is to big :(
I think it is because I do a recursive function IE and FF might not like that.... 
If I find the answer I will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of testing, it looks like NVD3 (the library I was using to make graphs easier) elements can't be found by jQuery **for the drop** on FF, IE, and Edge. Don't really know why but...

What I did to fix it is put the `draggable` and `droppable` on the dialog content NOT the NVD3 graph, and I prevented things I didn't want to drag from dragging.

Like this:

```
$("#" + id ).draggable();     // make the content of my dialog box draggable

        $("#" + id ).draggable({
        cancel: ".nv-context",     // that's a part I don't want to drag
        });

$("#" + id ).droppable();    // make the content of my dialog box droppable
```

This way it actually works, because I put the `droppable` on the dialog content not the graph. If somebody has an explanation for why this is, I will accept his answer. For now I accept mine.